# r different means different superscripts (or suffixes)

Tags: r, statistics

Journals sometimes report means with attached suffixes or superscripts, where means which do not share a suffix are statistically different. For example in Xa, Yab, Zb, X is different from Z, while Y is not different neither from X nor from Z. Here you can see a detailed description: http://www.jerrydallal.com/lhsp/similar.htm
I have two questions:
1. Is there an R package which can handle this?
2. If not, how difficult is to write a function? I spent a few hours, but couldn't find an easy solution, but I might be missing something.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching didn't seem that difficult. Perhaps you should spend more time learning the methods for searching for R related questions:

```
> findFn("Tukey HSD")   # function from 'sos' package 
found 36 matches;  retrieving 2 pages
2 
Downloaded 29 links in 17 packages.
> library(agricolae)
> data(sweetpotato)
> model<-aov(yield~virus, data=sweetpotato)
> out <- HSD.test(model,"virus", group=TRUE,console=TRUE,
+ main="Yield of sweetpotato\nDealt with different virus")

Study: Yield of sweetpotato
Dealt with different virus

HSD Test for yield 

Mean Square Error:  22.48917 

virus,  means

      yield      std r  Min  Max
cc 24.40000 3.609709 3 21.7 28.5
fc 12.86667 2.159475 3 10.6 14.9
ff 36.33333 7.333030 3 28.0 41.8
oo 36.90000 4.300000 3 32.1 40.4

alpha: 0.05 ; Df Error: 8 
Critical Value of Studentized Range: 4.52881 

Honestly Significant Difference: 12.39967 

Means with the same letter are not significantly different.

Groups, Treatments and means
a    oo      36.9 
ab   ff      36.33 
bc   cc      24.4 
c    fc      12.87
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!